# why document has getElementById method even though it doesnt inherit from Element?

Tags: javascript, dom, domdocument

Following the MDN docs, the [Element interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) holds all methods to search for dom nodes like

- getElementById
- getElementsByTagName
- ...

MDN also [states](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document) that Document inherits directly from Node. **NOT** from Element.

So why does Document hold all these Element methods (and methods from the ParentNode interface)?
Is MDN just not up to date with the specs or am I missing something?

Comment: It has its own method, it doesn't inherit it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: The Element interface does **not** include `getElementById()`. The `.getElementById()` method does not make sense as an Element method because it is inherently *global* to the document.

Comment: @Barmar seems like the german MDN is not up to date. Its listed as methods in en-US but not in de

Comment: @Pointy guess I need to edit the title and text. Thx for pointing out. //EDIT: nevermind since its referenced in the answer I let it as it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Both* `Document.prototype` and `Element.prototype` have `getElementsByTagName`. One isn't inheriting from the other - they're completely separate functions (unintuitively):

```js
console.log(
  Element.prototype.hasOwnProperty('getElementsByTagName'),
  Document.prototype.hasOwnProperty('getElementsByTagName'),
  Element.prototype.getElementsByTagName === Document.prototype.getElementsByTagName,
  Document.prototype.hasOwnProperty('getElementById'),
  Element.prototype.hasOwnProperty('getElementById'),
);
```

`Element.prototype` does *not* have `getElementById`.

The `ParentNode` interface is an *abstract specification*, not an actual Javascript object that you can examine somewhere. Both `Element.prototype` and `Document.prototype` implement it, but they do so by putting ParentNode methods directly on their prototypes. (`ParentNode` is *not at all* the same thing as Node)

Comment: I am aware that ParentNode is only an inteface and is implemented by both document and element. However; I kept wondering anyway. Thanks for the answer - helped a lot!